# Incomplete multithreading?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pool

I have the following Python code:

```py
pool = ThreadPool(32)
l = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

def func(e):
    if "$" in e:
        l["included"] += 1
    else:
        l["not_included"] += 1

with open(file_name) as file:
    data = file_name.readlines()

pool.map(func, data)

with open("output/logs.txt") as file:
    file.write(l)
```

Essentially, it is looking for lines in a file that contain the character "$". However, each time I execute the code, that output file is different, meaning that the list `l` being appended to is different. What could be causing this?

The confusing part is that the resulting defaultdict `l` differs from each execution. Sometimes `l = {"included": 772, "not_included": 9992}`, sometimes `l = {"included": 878, "not_included": 6907}` etc.

Comment: threads may fight for access to list, put elements in different order, overwrite, etc. you would have to use queue to send result with row number so it can put result in correct place.

Comment: as I remeber if threads will return values using `return` then pool should create list in correct order. `result = pool.map(func, data)`

Answer (score 0):

Each operation of `func` is taking a different amount of time. Consider:

```
>>> from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
>>> from random import randrange
>>> min_time = 0
>>> max_time = 4
>>> import time
>>> pool = ThreadPool(4)
>>> lst = []
>>> def func(e):
...     time.sleep(randrange(min_time, max_time))
...     lst.append(e ** 2)
... 
>>> data = list(range(20))
>>> pool.map(func, data)
>>> lst
[0, 4, 1, 36, 9, 16, 100, 121, 64, 81, 144, 49, 25, 169, 256, 289, 196, 225, 324, 361]
```

Each thread calls `func` but takes a different amount of time. Since there are multiple threads running at the same time, they aren't guaranteed to append in any order. 
Maybe the first thread starts with input 0, but takes 2 seconds, but the second thread starts with 1 and takes less than a second. In that case, the result of calling `func` with 1 is appended first.

Edit: I assume that the length of the file is the same, and order is the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've elaborated a little bit more on my exact use-case since I don't quite understand it still. I understand the different execution times for each `func` call, but I don't understand why I am geting different final results. The total execution time also changes.

Answer (score 0):

Because `map()` returns value from threads so I use it to return True or False and later count them in main thread. This way threads don't try to use the same `l` which often makes problem.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(32)

def func(e):
    return "$" in e

data = ['$','$','x','$','$','x','$','$','x','x','$','x','x']

results = pool.map(func, data)

print(results)

l = dict()
l["included"] = results.count(True)
l["not included"] = results.count(False)

print(l)
```

Result

```
[True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True, False, False]
{'included': 7, 'not included': 6}
```

---

Problem is when one thread is changing value but it doesn't block access to variable so at the same time other thread get old value instead of new one and it modify this old value and put it back to variable so it generate wrong result. Threads would have to use some Lock or Semaphor to block access to variable.